# WiX bootstrapper: Uninstall packages in a chain

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix-extension

```
 <ExePackage Id="PackageID1" DisplayName="xxx" Compressed="yes"
              SourceFile="..\xxx\MyExe.exe" Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="parameters to the exe"
              UninstallCommand="parameters to the exe"/>
```

When I trigger the Uninstall action:

```
this.Engine.Detect();
this.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
this.Engine.Apply(System.IntPtr.Zero);
```

The exePackage does not get invoked. However, during Install, it enters the exe package with the right parameters.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The log file Burn creates in %TEMP% can help you. Can you post this here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `DetectCondition` attribute on your `ExePackage` element. The `DetectCondition` is how the Burn engine determines if the package is installed on the machine or not. Without a `DetectCondition` the engine will think the package is never installed so it will never need to be uninstalled. Since all executables are different you have to provide your own `DetectCondition`. Usually the `XxxSearch` elements in the `util` namespace are helpful to detect if your executable is installed.

Note: you can see the 'plan' in the log file and it should show the `PackageID1` package being detected as `'Absent'` even though it is installed.